# Will Visual Studio 2008 Reporting Services work with SQL Server 2014?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

Will Visual Studio 2008 Reporting Services work with SQL Server 2014?

If not, should the report solutions be upgraded to the latest version of Visual Studio?

Which versions of Visual Studio Reporting Services work with SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between Visual Studio and SQL Server can be a bit confusing.

Reporting Services (the report server platform) is a component of **SQL Server**. Reporting Services *reports* can be designed using Microsoft's development environment tool Visual Studio. A Visual Studio shell is installed as part of SQL Server tools but is rebranded "Business Intelligence Development Studio" / BIDS in earlier versions of SQL Server and "SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence" / SSDT-BI in the 2012 and later releases.

Each release of SQL Server ships with a newer version of the Visual Studio shell for developing reports (also Integration Services packages and Analysis Services cubes). This changed slightly for SQL Server 2014 in that SSDT-BI was not installed with SQL Server tools but is instead available as a seperate download from Microsoft.

For the recent releases, the associated Visual Studio versions were:

```
SQL Server 2008 R2   (BIDS)    Visual Studio 2008
SQL Server 2012      (SSDT-BI) Visual Studio 2010
SQL Server 2014      (SSDT-BI) Visual Studio 2013
```

To design reports for SQL Server Reporting Services you need to be using the appropriate version of Visual Studio and the business intelligence components, so to answer your question: No, you will not be able to use Visual Studio 2008 to design reports that are compatible with SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services. For this you will need to download SSDT-BI (based on Visual Studio 2013) from Microsoft.

Download link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=42313