# Set compatibility level within SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create a report in SSRS with a dataset that does a cross-server query. The database being queried is SQL Server 2014, and I have set compatibility_level 110 on that database. SSRS is installed in a 2014 instance. The query doesn't currently retrieve any data from a database in the SSRS instance, but it will in the future which is why I've set this up as a cross-server query. I'm using the percentile_disc function which requires compatibility_level 110.

When I run the dataset query interactively (e.g. in TOAD) with the current database set to one of the SSRS instance DBs, it works. I had to set compatibility_level = 110 on both DBs to make this work.

When I paste the same query into the query builder in SSRS, it says

> The percentile_disc function is not allowed in the current compatibility mode.  It is only allowed in 110 mode or higher.

I checked the compatibility_level on the ReportServer$ database, and that's 120.  I've tried searching for this problem but all I can find is discussion on how to upgrade existing reports; I'm trying to create a new report, so I would expect it to use whatever compatibility_level it sees in the databases.  Is there some configuration setting I need in Visual Studio? Or does every single database on the SSRS instance need to be set to 110?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using to build the report?

Comment: VS Professional 2012, version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4.  It never occurred to me that that could be an issue, though I did look around for VS settings to see if I could find something relevant. I didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to build your report in VS 2013.

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829550/will-visual-studio-2008-reporting-services-work-with-sql-server-2014) for more information.

Comment: It does look like that's the issue.  When I installed VS 2013 two years ago it didn't support SSRS and it took me a week to cleanly uninstall it.  Now https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313 has the component needed to make it work.  Thanks.